# Request Header extract wrong data for webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, token

I try to create own token by using request header. My header is called IG-Token.
When i call ajax by using beforesend

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("IG-Token", ig.getToken());
```

I trace from developer tool i pass correct token. But after return back to client, my token is not using current token. Still grab old token. Mean different user (in different browser/different PC).

this is how i extract the token from webapi

```
var token = string.Empty;
var keyFound = Request.Headers.TryGetValues("IG-Token", out headerValues);
if (keyFound)
{
      userId = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}   
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, token);
```

Answer (score 0):

USE:
string token=Convert.ToString(Request.Headers["IG-Token"])

Comment: example token for computer A is 1234567890 and computer B is 0987654321. computer A call ajax with custom authentication by using ig-token is 1234567890. but after Computer B call ajax by ig-token, when i tried to retrieved  the request.header ig-token. the token is 1234567890. but after i refresh again, the ig-token become 0987654321. its look like retrieve the older ig-token. not the ig-token that i passed by ajax.

Comment: I think it is retrieving default token(not old token).

Comment: So If this is a case,you must have to remove default values. and make your code to accept values and assign tokens dynamically and persist with that values until modification of token.

Comment: its look like got cache. currently create 1 view that passing ig-token to webapi, and return back ig-token by retrieve request.header ig-token. first load ok. then i copy URL webapi. and paste to other browser. the webapi result will be shown the same ig-token.

Comment: before this i use normal http. it working perfect. but this happen when i move to https.